# How to setup port mappings with the Cling UPnP library

Tags: java, upnp, cling

Having looked through the [NAT Traversal Doc](http://4thline.org/projects/cling/support/manual/cling-support-manual.html#section.PortMapping) for Cling, I find myself with these questions:

- In the second example where does the mapping array come from?
- Can I (How to) query, after the setup, for the external port mapped to (host, internal_port)?
- IMPORTANT: If I set a finite lease on a mapping, how do I renew the lease?

Comment: i'm seaching for it too, look the users github samples...